# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'xy' (YOLOV8 | Deepface)

Tags: face-detection, yolov8, deepface, ultralytics

I'm running [deepface](https://github.com/serengil/deepface) model for face recognition and chose YOLOV8 for detecting face. Here is the code I'm running:

```
from deepface import DeepFace

result = DeepFace.verify(model_name='VGG-Face', detector_backend='yolov8', img1_path='img1.jpg', img2_path='img2.jpg')
```

So, when I run the code, I'm seeing this error message:

> left_eye = result.keypoints.xy[0][0], result.keypoints.conf[0][0]
>
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'xy'

I'm assuming that YOLOV8 is detecting face but can't detect keypoints for left/right eyes. I tested it with around 10 images but still failing.

What am I doing wrong? How to solve this problem?

Comment: A more detailed code example is needed, at least from the yolo prediction function calling to this point. Also, you can print the `result` to see what information it contains. From the description, it's hard to say if the result object is called properly or if the detection result is empty (no detection).

Comment: @hanna_liavoshka, I updated the question a bit

Answer (score 0):

The author made modification in deepface and now it's working fine (probably not in pip yet). The change was in [Yolo.py](https://github.com/serengil/deepface/blob/master/deepface/detectors/Yolo.py#L84) in lines 76-78. See github issue [here](https://github.com/serengil/deepface/issues/1077)

Changed from:

```
for result in results:
    # Extract the bounding box and the confidence
    x, y, w, h = result.boxes.xywh.tolist()[0]
    confidence = result.boxes.conf.tolist()[0]
```

to:

```
for result in results:

    if result.boxes is None or result.keypoints is None:
        continue

    # Extract the bounding box and the confidence
    x, y, w, h = result.boxes.xywh.tolist()[0]
    confidence = result.boxes.conf.tolist()[0]
```